# Cannot read property 'length' of null in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular material table. please check below code.

```
     <table mat-table [ngClass]="'arInvTb'" [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows #viewsort="matSort" matSort  matSortDirection="asc" (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" matSortActive="customSort" matSortDisableClear>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="errorCodeH">
  <th class="grid-center" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="min-width:100px"> Error</th>
  <td class="grid-left mytext" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
    <p *ngIf="element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH.length < 50">
    {{element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH}}                      
    </p>
  </td>
 </ng-container>
</table>
```

i am tying to show paragraph tag, with the condition. my problem is sometimes
errorCodeH come with 'null'. then error occurred. how i handle this error,
error is Cannot read property 'length' of null.

[image]

can u give me better solution for handle this.

Comment: I suppose the array `element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH` is empty so you are getting this error

Answer (score 2):

Just check for a [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value before accessing `length`:

```
<table mat-table [ngClass]="'arInvTb'" [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows #viewsort="matSort" matSort  matSortDirection="asc" (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" matSortActive="customSort" matSortDisableClear>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="errorCodeH">
  <th class="grid-center" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="min-width:100px"> Error</th>
  <td class="grid-left mytext" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
    <p *ngIf="element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH && element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH.length < 50">
    {{element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH}}                      
    </p>
  </td>
 </ng-container>
</table>
```

When you use **and operator** in javascript `&&`, second operand will just be evaluated if first is *truthy*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, verify that `errorCodeH` is not null, then use `.length`.
Something like this:

```
element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH ? 
element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH.length < 50 ? 
'Smaller than 50' : 
'Greater than 50' : 
'Is null'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the null safety operator(?.) inside the html before accessing the value like Below.

```
<p *ngIf="element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH?.length < 50">
    {{element.arInvoiceHeader.errorCodeH}}                      
</p>
```

In the above example, `errorCodeH?.length` if errorCodeH is null or undefined, then we won't get any error and if is not null and not undefined, then length is accessed.